# Hovering over mat-card

Tags: html, angular, hover

How to show mat-card-action on hover over card. When i hover over one card it shows action for every card.

```
 <mat-card (mouseover)="hover=true" (mouseleave)="hover=false" [className]="flashcard.privatno ? 'privatno' : 'javno'" *cdkVirtualFor = "let flashcard of flashcards; let i = index" (click)="loadOne(i)">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{seci(flashcard.pitanje)}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions >
        <button mat-button *ngIf="hover==true">LIKE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
[Hovering over first card. It should show only LIKE on that card and not on the other][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Bsp.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `*ngIf="hover==true"` you are comparing all the elements of the for loop with the same variable, that's why all will display/hide at the same time. You need a way to differentiate each element. If your flashcard item have an id, you can try something like this:

.html:

```
<mat-card (mouseover)="toggleHover(flashcard.id)" (mouseleave)="removeHover()" [className]="flashcard.privatno ? 'privatno' : 'javno'" *cdkVirtualFor = "let flashcard of flashcards; let i = index" (click)="loadOne(i)">
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{seci(flashcard.pitanje)}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions >
        <button mat-button *ngIf="hoveredElement === flashcard.id ">LIKE</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

.ts

```
public hoveredElement:any;

toggleHover(id) {
  this.hoveredElement = id
}

removeHover() {
  this.hoveredElement = null;
}
```